# Em qual tabela o wordpress armazena o layout dos posts?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Preciso atualizar posts antigos com um layout novo, eu queria saber em qual tabela do banco do wordpress fica o layout dos posts alguém tem idéia?, obs tenho que alterar sem ser pelo painel de adm, Obrigatoriamente tem que ser pelo banco.

Comment: Até onde tenho conhecimento sobre os temas do WP, os layouts e seus respectivos templates, não são salvos no banco. Os arquivos ficam em `wp-content/themes/nome-do-seu-tema`. [Aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Hierarquia_de_Modelos_WordPress) você acha os nomes dos arquivos dos temas, suas funções e a sua respectiva arquitetura organizacional.

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo Sim, mas aquele determinado post, tem que saber qual tema está usando de algum modo certo?, será que não há alguma tabela que diga que está usando aquele determinado thema ou layout? Pois e os posts antigos?

Comment: Sim, no banco é salvo o nome do tema que vc está usando. Aí pelo nome salvo ele encontra a pasta relativa ao tema e busca seus respectivos arquivos de layout dentro da mesma. A referência no banco ao tema fica na tabela `wp_options` (se o banco tiver sido instalado com o prefixo `wp_`). [Nesse link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db) pode te mostrar como visualizar essas informações e possivelmente fazer alguma alteração.

Comment: Certooo Obrigado @HamurabiAraujo